# Validating That A has_many Association Has At Least One Model When Using FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, factory

Putting aside arguments on whether or not you should test existence of a model's associations, I have a model called `Order` and I am validating that it has at least one `item` in its `has_many` association using:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :items

  validates :items, presence: true

end
```

I have set FactoryGirl to lint my factories (checking for validity). So my order factory is not valid unless I create an item for its `has_many` collection.

My `orders` factory looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :order do

    ignore do
      items_count 1
    end

    after(:build) do |order, evaluator|
      create_list(:item, evaluator.items_count, order: order)
    end

  end
end
```

According to Factory Girl's *Getting Started*:

```
FactoryGirl.lint builds each factory and subsequently calls #valid? on it
```

However when I run my specs, Factory Girl throws an `FactoryGirl::InvalidFactoryError` because the order factory is invalid.

**Workaround**

```
after(:build) do |order, evaluator|
   evaluator.items_count.times do
     order.items << FactoryGirl.create(:item)
   end
   #create_list(:item, evaluator.items_count, order: order)
 end
```

Comment: You're doing a `create_list(:item)`, do you have `item` factory defined?

Comment: Yes. The item factory is there and is valid.

Comment: I think you should be using `after(:create)` instead of `after(:build)` for this because with just build the `order` is not saved and there is no `order_id` for `items`.

Comment: @vee but if it validates the presence of at least one item, how can it be created without one?

Comment: I think `validates :items, presence: true` check if `items.present?` returns true/false. `order.items` returns `[]` for new object. `[].present?` returns true. So validation passes correctly

Comment: @gotva `[].present?` does not return true.

Comment: @Pedr In your workaround, did you mean `order.items << FactoryGirl.create(:item, order: order)`, or are you relying on the item factory to create a different order? Does an item have one or many orders?

Comment: oh, about `[].present? # => true`  I am wrong. I recheck Rails 4.1.1 works as expected and validation failed - record is invalid without `items`. Maybe Rails version is important for this stuff.

Comment: Does it work if you use build_list instead of create_list?

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition, it will call `.valid?` AFTER building. It seems that it will call this before running the `after(:build)` block.

Try writing you factory like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :order do

    ignore do
      items_count 1
    end

    items { build_list(:item, items_count) }

  end
end
```

This should build the item before the `.valid?` is called.

Let me know if this works :)